# How do I install bootchart on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ppa, bootchart

Is [bootchart](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/admin/bootchart) no longer available? Is there an equivalent graphical tool?

```
sudo apt install bootchart  
E: Package 'bootchart' has no installation candidate
 sudo snap install bootchart
error: snap "bootchart" not found
```

My analyze chain does not seem helpful at all:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.



graphical.target @17.301s
└─multi-user.target @17.301s
  └─snap-node-2082.mount @56.794s +60ms
    └─local-fs-pre.target @1.903s
      └─keyboard-setup.service @226ms +1.367s
        └─systemd-journald.socket @224ms
          └─system.slice @218ms
            └─-.slice @218ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package name changed for systemd from `bootchart` to `systemd-bootchart`

Try installing `systemd-bootchart` in 18.04 and newer.

Comment: Wow, somehow my zsh apt autocomplete missed this AND the software center didn't show it. I never use apt search anymore since normally the autocomplete is so perfect